# Unable to select text using pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I want to select some text on the screen. I figured using pyautogui would be the way to go. I did the following:

```
keyDown('shift')
sleep(0.1)
press('end')
sleep(0.1)
keyUp('shift')
```

When doing this exact combination by hand it does select the text I want it to. Of course the sleep function is from the time module.

I even tried to select text in word using the following:

```
keyDown('shift')
press('right')
press('right')
keyUp('shift')
```

And even this didn't work...
Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lore Thanks for putting up the bounty. Made me look into this again! I can finally continue my project again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer!
It wasn't selecting text for me as long as `num lock` was enabled.

Make sure `num lock` is disabled when using `pyautogui`

Answer (score 1):

You do not use `click` twice. Here is an example on how to do it from the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html):

```
pyautogui.doubleClick()
```

**PS: I tkink you wanted to do left click...**

Answer (score 0):

Just found out about 'hotkey' function.
Appears to be faster than the single key variation as well.

Example for a copy text and paste per line macro:

```
import pyautogui as pyg

def macro():

    pyg.press('home')
    pyg.hotkey('shiftleft', 'end')
    pyg.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    pyg.press('end')
    pyg.press('enter')
    pyg.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    pyg.press('down')

i = macro()

# Do macro 10 times
for i in range(10):
    macro()
```